# What is the rule of thumb for built up beams with splices

Tags: beam, splices

The attached spec would lead me to derive that I could build a beam out of many splices as long as the spliced member is overlapped by a non splice by 9" and nailed 4.5" out from the splice on each side.

I've always done built up beams from full length members.  Do people generally just slap them together with scrap?

[image: built up beam splice]

Comment: I wonder how manufacturers of beams stay in business if all it takes is nailing together a bunch of scrap to make a beam.  Perhaps there is more do it than shown in the diagram...

Comment: The biggest problem I see is 1) does not specify required lap distance at various “zones” within the span of the beam, 2) does not specify diameter of nails, 3) percentage of allowable load for full length members.

Comment: Aren't nails > 3.5" long nails going to almost always be quite thick?  The laps in the diagram are in the middle of the span so aren't those going to be the ones that require the largest lap?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger If the middle is critical for the lap (and I agree that it is) why would you not specify the lap distance and number of nails.

Comment: @LeeSam I'd assume the nails are 16d given that is the only 3.5" nail in the simpson pocket installers guide.  For the lap I take it from your comment that you don't think 9" (4.5 either side of the splice is going to be enough?) and that if a built up beam is constructed this way it will have less allowable load than a non splice built beam?  Thanks for the discussion !

Comment: @isherwood - do you ever do splices in headers/beams?